# Convert HashMap<String,List> into a JAXB Response

Tags: jaxb, hashmap

Basically I have a **HashMap** which I like it to be converted to JAXB representation. My aim is to get the data in the following format:

```
  <MetaAttributes>
   <MetaAttribute>
     Name: ABC
        MetaName: a1
        MetaName: b1
        MetaName: c1
        MetaName: d1
    <MetaAttribute>
    <MetaAttribute>
     Name: DEF
        MetaName: w1
        MetaName: x1
        MetaName: y1
        MetaName: z1
    <MetaAttribute>
  </MetaAttributes>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: map is of type HashMap<String,List>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `XmlAdapter` to customize how a `HashMap` is coverted to/from XML.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XSD of desired XML schema and then generate JAXB classes from it.

When you have the generated classes, it is very easy to convert from a HashMap (or whatever) to JAXB classes, with an adapter class, for example.